# Python Application to Generate random txt files: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python

I am having this problem with some code I have written. What I am trying to do is create an application which creates a txt file with a random name then write some data in it. But I keep on getting an error.

Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I understand what the error means and everything, just how do I get around it? I need the open function as a string so I can insert the randomized number in it.

```
from random import random

def create():
    number = random()
    makefile = "open(\'" + str(number) + ".txt\'"',' "\'w+\')"
    print("File has been created")
    makefile.write("Hello")
    makefile.close()

create()
```

**EDIT**: Thanks Xdhmoore for your post. This question has been answered:

Solution:

*I don't think you need the open function name as a string. Wouldn't makefile = open(str(number) + ".txt", "w+") work? – xdhmoore 2 mins ago*

Comment: I don't think you need the open function name as a string. Wouldn't `makefile = open(str(number) + ".txt", "w+")` work?

Comment: You don't need the `open` command to be a string, just the filename portion

Comment: Thanks Xdhmoore. What you suggested worked well! Thx

Answer (score 0):

`open` in your code is string, not command. Try below,

```
makefile = open(str(number) + ".txt", "w+")

makefile.write("Hello")
```